# Groovy Couchbase help needed

Tags: groovy, couchbase

I am beginner in Groovy and Couchbase. Used Groovy-console to script some basic Groovy. Used couchbase console tool with UI to meddle with documents on couchbase. Now I wanna combine them. I want to meddle with documents in couchbase using Groovy script.

Where can I find an apt tutorial? Or an example code of Groovy-couchbase connection and operation will also help a lot.

(I couldn't find on Google searches, so had to turn to my fellow experts on stackoverflow)

Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Basically I am searching for a tutorial or a code snippet that would help me build connection to couchbase, in my local server(localhost), using a Groovy script. So that I can perform INSERT,UPDATE,DETELE,etc. operations on Couchbase through the Groovy script.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the Java client.

```
@Grab('com.couchbase.client:java-client:2.2.6')

import com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster

// Connect to localhost 
def cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create()

// Open the default bucket and the "beer-sample" one 
def defaultBucket = cluster.openBucket()
def beerSampleBucket = cluster.openBucket("beer-sample")

// Disconnect and clear all allocated resources 
cluster.disconnect()
```

The Java client documentation is here: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/java-2.2/java-intro.html

Comment: Tysm !! Worked!! :-)

Comment: Hey, Whenever i am running N1QL queries. it says java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException.. Could you please help me on this.. I will share the code, Whatever i have done.. Here is the link whatever I have done - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986045/unable-to-create-primary-index-on-couchbase-using-groovy-script