# Unable to create primary index on couchbase using groovy script

Tags: java, groovy, couchbase, sql++

I am not able to Create primary index on couchbase using groovy script. Below are the lines of code I used:-

```
@Grab('com.couchbase.client:java-client:2.2.6')

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket;
import com.couchbase.client.java.Cluster;
import com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster;
import com.couchbase.client.java.document.JsonDocument;
import com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject;
import com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster
import com.couchbase.client.java.query.N1qlQuery;
import com.couchbase.client.java.query.N1qlQueryResult;
import com.couchbase.client.java.query.N1qlQueryRow;
import com.couchbase.client.java.query.SimpleN1qlQuery;
import com.couchbase.client.java.env.CouchbaseEnvironment;
import com.couchbase.client.java.env.DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment;

CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder().connectTimeout(10000).build();
def cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(env, IPADDRESS);
def bucket = cluster.openBucket(BUCKET_NAME, BUCKET_PASSWORD);
log.info "Connection done"

String queryString = "CREATE PRIMARY INDEX `PrimInd` ON BUCKET_NAME"
bucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple(queryString))

log.info "Primary index created"
```

It gives me error as below :-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException at this line:-

bucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple(queryString))
```

Connection is being done properly and same query works in couchbase server. So, I think there is problem with my code.

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Shouldn't `"CREATE PRIMARY INDEX \`PrimInd\` ON \`BUCKET_NAME\`"`  be  `"CREATE PRIMARY INDEX \`PrimInd\` ON \`$BUCKET_NAME\`"`?

Comment: Okey, You mean if BUCKET_NAME is demo then i should use this query? -  CREATE PRIMARY INDEX `PrimInd` ON `$demo`"

Comment: No.  You use a variable `BUCKET_NAME` further up the script, then the literal `BUCKET_NAME` in the query

Comment: Ok, If my bucket name is Demo.. How to write the query?

Comment: @Simon Baslé - Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Couchbase Java client, the `query()` method delegates to a `Blocking` API which uses JavaRx under the covers. The [source](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/java/util/Blocking.java#L55) code for the Blocking API states:

> If an error happens inside the `Observable`, it will be raised
>   as an `Exception`. **If the timeout kicks in, a `TimeoutException` nested in a `RuntimeException` is thrown** to be fully compatible with the `Observable.timeout(long, TimeUnit)` behavior.

You're experiencing a `TimeoutException` nested in a `RuntimeException`, hence the root cause is that your query is timing out.

`DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment` [defaults](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/java/env/DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.java#L66) to a *queryTimeout* (the timeout [used](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/java/CouchbaseBucket.java#L574) for N1qlQuery queries) of 75 milli-seconds. You can change this default with the environment builder:

```
def env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
    .connectTimeout(10000)
    .queryTimeout(10000) // This is the query timeout
    .build()
```

Comment: I'll try with the above code and let you know. Thanks for responding.